# font looks thinner in adobe/acrobat reader

Tags: adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

Why do fonts look thinner in adobe and different and richer in sumatra pdf.

**Sumatra**
[image: Sumatra PDF]

**Adobe**
[image: Adobe PDF]

**Adobe reader settings:**

[image]

Comment: @techie007 : I have the same setting as its shown in your comment answer.